# jquery mouseover not working. working in jfiddle only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseover

It's just a couple of lines of code: http://jsfiddle.net/z7bHt/

HTML:

```
<body>
<img src="http://pjg.mobi/mh/images/layover_brownstring.png" id="bowleft" width="200" height="77" alt=""/> 
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$("#bowleft").mouseenter(function(){
    console.log("worked!!!");alert("worked!!!");
});
```

but this simple mouseover isn't working, locally or remotely, in either chrome or firefox!

Could someone try this themselves to see if i'm going crazy or if it is my operating system? https://www.dropbox.com/s/ahpaluj2e7ru9xn/mouseover.zip

Comment: what version of jquery are you including in your html?

Answer (score 2):

The `.mouseenter` code is running before the `#bowleft` element exists.  You need to ensure that it runs after that element exists in the DOM. There are many ways to do this.  I would suggest moving your JavaScript to right before `</body>`.  You can also wrap it in:

```
$(function () {
```

Or `$(document).ready(function () {`, which is functionally the same.

I would also suggest using `.on` instead of the specific function named after the event, but this doesn't affect you here.  All together:

```
<body>
    <img src="http://pjg.mobi/mh/images/layover_brownstring.png" id="bowleft" width="200" height="77" alt=""/>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#bowleft").on("mouseenter", function () {
            console.log("worked!!!");
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reference the image with your JS before it exists in the DOM.

The best thing to do is to move your JS to just before the closing body tag, like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <img src="http://pjg.mobi/mh/images/layover_brownstring.png" id="bowleft" width="200" height="77" alt=""/> 
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $("#bowleft").mouseenter(function(){
        console.log("worked!!!");
        alert("worked!!!");
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you want to keep it in the head of the document, you'll have to wrap it in a `$(document).ready()` callback.

Answer (score 0):

try this it worked ........

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#bowleft").mouseenter(function () {
            console.log("worked!!!"); alert("worked!!!");
        });
    });
```